# access grunt serve inside docker

Tags: docker, gruntjs, yeoman

I made 2 docker image( nginx, yeoman) and mapped port as below.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
3a71ee900cc0        webserver:0.1       "nginx"             About an hour ago   Up About an hour    443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   webserver
af57b93ca326        silarsis/yeoman     "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp          yeoman
```

And get into yeoman docker to make grunt server.

```
yeoman_docker$ yo  ..scafolding stuff  
yeoman_docker$ ls  
Gruntfile.js README.md  app  bower.json  bower_components  node_modules  package.json  test  
yeoman_docker$ grunt serve 
Running "serve" task


    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2016-09-23 07:20:28 UTC-0)
    loading tasks                5ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 19%
    loading grunt-contrib-copy  13ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 50%
    copy:styles                  8ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 31%
    Total 26ms

Running "autoprefixer:server" (autoprefixer) task Autoprefixer's process() method is deprecated and will removed in next major release. Use postcss([autoprefixer]).process() instead File .tmp/styles/main.css created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000

Running "watch" task Waiting...
```

Keep this SSH to maintain grunt serve.
Nginx is accessable from local (127.0.0.1:8080) But grunt is not able to access(127.0.0.1:9000). Is there any difference between making grunt server in local and docker?  What should I do with it?

It seems that grunt server is not on local.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 10.0.8.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:39682         TIME_WAIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your connect server in the yeoman container listens to localhost inside the container:

```
Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000
```

When creating a port binding with docker the service inside the docker container has to listen to host `0.0.0.0`, not `localhost`. You need to update your `gruntfile.js` so that you connect server listens to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: You got me! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Been there myself. ;) Happy hacking!